# Complete List of immutable JDK classes?

Tags: immutability, java

is there a list of **de-facto** immutable classes in the jdk?

technically Immutable classes include the obvious Integer, Double etc..

de-facto immutable will include for example java.lang.String - it might technically be mutable but de-facto it is not.

Also, are there Interfaces/Abstract classes which are required (as stated in the javadoc) to be immutable?

if you cannot provide a complete List, i would already be happy if you know a bunch of classes which state immutability in its javadoc..

Comment: not a de facto list but some immutable classes are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124012/immutable-classes

Comment: i would download the javadocs html archive and grep them for "immutable" and proceed.. but thats just me.

Comment: How do you define `de facto immutable`, how `technically immutable`?

Comment: de facto: as stated in the javadoc; technically: final classes, all fields final, do not contain arrays or interfaces/abstract classes as fields, all fields technically immutable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I try to compile the list as much as I can:

1. java.lang.String
   The wrapper classes for the primitive types:
2. java.lang.Integer
3. java.lang.Byte
4. java.lang.Character
5. java.lang.Short
6. java.lang.Boolean
7. java.lang.Long
8. java.lang.Double
9. java.lang.Float
10. java.lang.StackTraceElement (used in building exception stacktraces)
11. Most of the enum classes
12. java.math.BigInteger
13. java.math.BigDecimal
14. java.io.File
15. java.awt.Font
16. java.awt.BasicStroke
17. java.awt.Color
18. java.awt.GradientPaint,
19. java.awt.LinearGradientPaint
20. java.awt.RadialGradientPaint,
21. java.awt.Cursor
22. java.util.Locale
23. java.util.UUID
24. java.util.Collections
25. java.net.URL
26. java.net.URI
27. java.net.Inet4Address
28. java.net.Inet6Address
29. java.net.InetSocketAddress
30. most subclasses of java.security.Permission

Comment: Classes of the [Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) must be included also.

Comment: This is a useful list.  I think it would make sense to exclude non-instantiable classes, like `Collections`.

Comment: What about java.lang.Object?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [MutabilityDetector](https://mutabilitydetector.github.io/MutabilityDetector/) and feed it JARs from the JDK to enumerate most immutable classes. It's "most" because it's so strict that even the [tiny bit of state change in java.lang.String](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#121) is enough to make it considered mutable, but the goal is to account for this by 1.0 release.

You can download the latest JAR here: https://github.com/MutabilityDetector/MutabilityDetector/releases

Here's an example of it's use. This is what I used to get most of the immutable JDK 1.7 classes on OSX:

`java -jar MutabilityDetector-0.9.5.jar -r IMMUTABLE -cp /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar`

Here's the output (slightly cleaned up):
https://gist.github.com/CalebFenton/85fc87edf64033afe110

I needed to do this for Android framework classes. The tricky part was finding a JAR with Android classes, and not just stubs which is the one included in the SDK. The good people at [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) make one, which you can download here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22android-all%22

You can see the list of immutable Android classes I use, which includes many JDK classes here:
https://github.com/CalebFenton/simplify/blob/master/smalivm/src/main/resources/immutable_classes.cfg

Answer (score -7):

Classes whose object contents cannot be modified is called immutable classes. All primitive data types(Wrapper classes only) are immutable. For any class to be immutable the following needs to be done.

- Make all fields private
- Don't provide mutators
- Ensure that methods can't be overridden by either making the class
  final (Strong Immutability) or making your methods final (Weak
  Immutability)
- If a field isn't primitive or immutable, make a deep clone on the way
  in and the way out.

Thank you

Comment: I think, primitives are mutable.

Comment: Primitives are but their wrapper classes are not.

Comment: primitives are values and thus not changable. primitive fields might be final or not final leading to non-immutable classes. primitive wrapper classes have only a final field with the primitive and are thus final

Comment: This answer doesn't even attempt to answer the question which is calling for a preferably exhaustive list of classes native to Java.

Comment: What a generic, uninformative answer. This is the kind of terrible answer you would expect from a tech support forum, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: `I think, primitives are mutable.`++