# cross-thread visibility of `volatile Double`

Tags: java, double, volatile

Does a `volatile Double` have cross-thread visibility the way `volatile double` has?

From the [Java Tutorials at Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) is the following:

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency
>   errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a
>   happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same
>   variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always
>   visible to other threads. What's more, it also means that when a
>   thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change
>   to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the
>   change.

It would seem to depend upon whether a Double is a special kind of object or an object that has nothing special about it.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote, please?

Comment: It's unclear to me what distinction you're trying to make between `Double` and `double` (or whatever other type). What do you mean by _special_?

Comment: Is an assignment to an existing Double a change to an object reference or a change to an existing object. If it's a change to an object, then the cross-thread visibility of a reference is of no benefit. Right?

Comment: `volatile` is a field _modifier_. It modifies a _variable_. If you assign a value to a variable, you're modifying the variable, not any object.

Comment: there is nothing special about a Double.  it is a normal Object the same as any other Object in java.  so yes, assigning a volatile Double reference will be correctly visible across threads.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis: `Double bigD = new Double(1); bigD = 2.0;` You're saying the object known as bigD did  not get modified?

Comment: bigD is a variable, not an Object.  that example includes two Double instances.  one is created in each assignment.  (FYI, Double objects are immutable).

Comment: Read: [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference)

Comment: jtahlborn: Interesting. If a Double is immutable, then `bigD = 2.0;` is a reference assignment and we know reference assignments have cross-thread visibility when the declaration is volatile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
volatile Double bigD = new Double(1.0); 
bigD = 2.0;
```

`Double` is an immutable class, as pointed out by jtahlborn. There is no change to the original object instance because it is immutable. The change to `bigD` is necessarily a reference change. That change benefits from the cross-thread visibility caused by the `volatile` declaration.

[A list of Java immutables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998031/complete-list-of-immutable-jdk-classes)

[Examples of Java immutables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124012/examples-of-immutable-classes)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, changes to a `volatile` variable in one thread are guaranteed to be seen when any thread subsequently accesses that variable, regardless of whether the variable is a primitive type or a reference type. However, this does *not* prevent thread synchronization issues - you must still ensure that two threads are not trying to change the variable simultaneously.

Comment: But if an assignment to an existing Double is a change to it's content then the reference hasn't changed in which case there's no change to be made visible across threads. Right?

Comment: A thread might be accessing a cached copy of the Double for increased speed. When the thread needs that Double, the current value isn't always retrieved directly from memory - it may be from a cached copy of the Double, which could be out of date.

Comment: What do you mean by _you must still ensure that two threads are not trying to change the variable simultaneously_? The `volatile` insures atomicity of the variable modification.

Comment: What does "cached copy of the Double" mean? The whole point of `volatile` is the memory barrier.

Comment: @chrylis I mean if the variable were not declared as `volatile`, not changing the reference does not ensure accessing the reference will reflect the true current state of the variable.