# Collections.sort sorts the wrong list

Tags: java, arrays, methods, collections

I want to create one sorted list out of my original list - without the `Collections.sort(list)` call changing the original list. So that I have one list unsorted and one being sorted - out of the same list.

Take a look at this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(6);
    System.out.println("Before method list is");
    System.out.println(list);
    ArrayList<Integer> theReturnedList = sorted(list);
    System.out.println("After it is");
    System.out.println(list);
}

private static ArrayList<Integer> sorted(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    ArrayList<Integer> returnList = list;
    Collections.sort(returnList);
    return returnList;
}
```

The `list` object gets sorted - even though I am not calling the `Collection.sort()` method onto it. How can I avoid it?

Beacuse I thought this would happen...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String original = "I am an object created in main";
    String theChangedObject = change(original);
    System.out.println(original);
}

private static String change(String string){
    String changed = string;
    changed = "I was changed";
    return changed;
}
```

The object `orginal` stays the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: What do you think that `ArrayList<Integer> returnList = list;` does?

Comment: You understand how reference types work?

Comment: I think so. This does not happen with a String object for instance?

Comment: Use `List<SomeBean> newList = new ArrayList<SomeBean>(otherList);` to avoid the reference problem.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Mendoza How is a String object different from a ArrayList object in that regard?

Comment: @lelelo: Barring via reflection, `String`s are immutable -- everything that would modify a string, instead returns a new string containing the modifications. So you never have a point where one string could be modified and the other not, because none of them can be modified in the first place.

Comment: @lelelo read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java) for further explanation.

Comment: @cHao ah that explains it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
ArrayList<Integer> returnList = list;
```

you are just creating another reference to the **same list** (Object) in your `sorted` method and any change that you apply to it using this new reference will be reflected in you original reference because they *point* to the same object. You can do this to create a new list:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> sorted(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    ArrayList<Integer> returnList = new ArrayList<>(list); // the new keyword creates a new object on the memory heap
    Collections.sort(returnList);
    return returnList;
}
```

This time we are creating *another* ArrayList Object with the elements of you original list. This way the original list won't change when you sort the newer.

This behaviour doesn't apply on [Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) like String or LocalDateTime. These cannot change their state after being created and instead return a new copy with the changes applied.

Comment: Do you happen to know where there is a complete list of all the Immutable objects? It could be good to know that. There is question for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998031/complete-list-of-immutable-jdk-classes

Comment: There is another list of immutable objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124214/7694740).  
Classes of the [Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) must be included also.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of how references work. Let's take a look at the method:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> sorted(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    ArrayList<Integer> returnList = list;
    Collections.sort(returnList);
    return returnList;
}
```

The line `ArrayList<Integer> returnList = list;` does **not** copy the list. It copies the *reference* to the list. What this means is that `returnList` and `list` will both refer to *the same list*. Changes in one will affect the other, because they are actually just different names for the same thing.

What you want to do is to make a brand new list containing the same values, which can be done with

```
ArrayList<Integer> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
returnList.addAll(list);
```

There is also a convenient `ArrayList` constructor that does this in one step:

```
ArrayList<Integer> returnList = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Changes to `returnList` will not affect `list` because they are now two completely independent lists that just happen to contain the same values.

Comment: Yes that worked. How come I do not have to do that with a String though?

Comment: String methods are immutable in Java.

Answer (score 3):

In your `sorted` method you are still calling `Collection.sort` on the original list. To avoid this you could create a shallow copy and return that e.g.

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> sorted(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    ArrayList<Integer> returnList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.sort(returnList);
    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Stream api

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,8,3,6);

List<Integer> newList = list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The stream api offers several methods to work with collections immutably. This is the recommended way if you are using Java 8 or later.