# How wrapper objects work?

Tags: java

Code Snippet

```
public class WrapperClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i1 = 400;
        Integer i2 = i1;
        i1++;
        System.out.println(i1 + "  " + i2);
    }
}
```

Output is `401 400` . I am not sure how wrapper objects work. Arent i1 and i2 pointing to same object ? What happens on java heap when the above code executes ?

Comment: [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166348/are-all-primitive-wrapper-classes-immutable-objects)

Comment: What else did you expect? `401 401`? Please read the Java documents...

Comment: Thanks  @KevinEsche i marked my question as duplicate :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple, Wrapper classes are immutable. To explain in detail:-

```
Integer i1 = 400;
Integer i2 = i1;
```

Now `i1` and `i2` point to the same object.

with this `i1++` , a new object (with value 401) is created and assigned to `i1`, while `i2` still continues to point to the old object (with value 400).

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct. Reason behind this is `Integer` immutability.

Comment: That does not answer most of his question.

Comment: @ThomasStets probably yes, but is more than enough to find out a missing part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course all wrapper classes are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very hard to understand

```
i1++;
```

means

```
i1 = new Integer(i1.intValue()+1);
```

Comment: What's hard to understand is how you'd write your own wrapper class to do that.  It's not like java lets you overload operators.