# Hiding mutators, clarification needed

Tags: java, design-patterns, encapsulation, data-hiding

Suppose you have a class `Dog`, that has

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;
    private double age;

    // some setters
    // some getters
```

Additionally, you have a class `DogHandler`, that makes an instance of the `Dog d` and passes it to `Owner`

I suppose, i can

... make a copy of a Dog before passing it to `Owner`, but that's an expensive operation and i'd rather avoid it.

... come up with an interface that  `Dog` implements which contains getters only, cast `Dog` to that interface and pass the result along

... initialize settable variables in a constructor and simply not allow changes for this instance of an object

**Are there any other ways to make sure receiver of the object cant modify it?**

How do you take a simple bean containing some data and make it read-only?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124012/immutable-classes) on immutable classes.

Comment: I find creating a base inteface that clients deal with like `Dog` for example and then a concrete implementation `MutableDog` which has setters works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in few ways, I can propose you 2 of them:

a) interface with getters is good idea

b) create derived class from Dog which has setters method blocked, like this:

```
class UnmodifiedDog extends Dog {
    public UnmodifiedDog(double age, String name) {
        super.setAge(age);
        super.setName(name);
    }
    @Override
    public void setAge(double age) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }   
}
```

In DogHandler:

```
Dog createDog() {
    return new UnmodifiedDog(10, "Fido");
}
```

and you can pass this to the Owner:

```
owner.receiveDog(dogHandler.createDog());
```

Comment: Why not to use existing `Dog` class as data source instead of passing age and name parameters to UnmodifiedDof constructor? That is like with `Collections.unmodifyableList`

Comment: @Misha, This is important if you have a lot fields to set, like in Lists or other collections. In this case I have only 2 fields, so it doesn't matter if I pass Dog in constructor or just 2 fields. But for more fields, yeah, your proposition is better approach

Answer (score 0):

The approaches you mention in the question are pretty much the standard steps to take to make `Dog` immutable. The only other tip would be to mandate that `Dog` cannot be overridden by declaring the class to be `final`.

Comment: change class to final won't work in this case, you can still change what is inside Dog: age and name.

Comment: @smas, you're right. I digressed and started talking about immutable _classes_, whereas the original question was about immutable _objects_.

Answer (score 0):

Among the solutions mentioned here, you can also take advantage of visibility modifiers.  If `Dog` and `Owner` are in separate packages, you can set the visibility of the mutators to default (package) scope or protected scope.

This will allow you to keep `Dog` and `DogHandler` in the same package (and therefore allow them both to mutate the `Dog` object accordingly), while keeping `Owner` objects separate (and therefore preventing them from making any modification to the `Dog` objects).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an interface and package access setters.

```
package blah.animal;
public interface Dog
{
  double getAge();
  String getName();
}

package blah.animal;
public class DogImpl implements Dog
{
  private double age; // double seems wrong for age.
  private String name;

  ... getters (defined by Dog interface)

  // package access setters.
  void setAge(double newValue)
  {
    age = newValue;
  }

  void setName(String newValue)
  {
    name = newValue;
  }

  package blah.animal;
  public class DogHandler
  {
    public static Dog newDog(double age, String name)
    {
      Dog returnValue = new DogImpl();
      returnValue.setAge(age);
      returnValue.setName(name);

      return returnValue;
    }
  }

  package.blah.somethingelse;
  public class Blam
  {
    private Dog myDog;

    public Blam()
    {
      myDog = DogHandler.newDog(1.4D, "Tippy");
    }
  }
```